# Can not add project to CI in gitlab 8.1.3

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to setup the CI deployment on gitlab for days.
I found that gitlab-ci had been integrated into gitlab after 8.0. But I can't find my projects in CI page, and can't press the button to add them to CI.

My server is ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS trusty. The latest version of gitlab omnibus package and sameersbn's CE docker both failed. Maybe the older version will work for me?

If anyone has the same problem, please give me some hints.

Comment: I do seem to have the same problem. Updated to 8.1.3 and now my projects are not visible in the CI menu tab...

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution. As soon as I committed something to the repository, a build automatically triggered and my project automatically showed in the CI projects.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled Gitlab CI service for your project?

To set up a Gitlab CI for your project go to the project page, then navigate to Settings -> Services, click on "GitLab CI", then check "Activate".

After that project should appear in CI page.

You would need to set up a runner for a project, either use a shared one or assign a specific one.